# 2 SPI Slaves with 2 different SPI modes on one Arduino Mega

Tags: spi, sd-card

I am working on a project where I read 8 MAX31856 thermocouple sensors using the Adafruit Library. This works just fine and prints the read outs to serial.

I want to also save the readings to a microSD card. And this is where I hit a snag.

I am trying to use the `SdFat.h` library. I can loop through my MAX31856 thermocouples, and write once to my SD card, but after that it hangs the SPI bus.

the MAX31856 works on SPI_MODE1 (as per [Adafruit Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MAX31856/blob/master/Adafruit_MAX31856.cpp)) and the microSD card works on SPI_MODE0, I believe. I am trying to switch SPI bus modes before and after writing to the SD card but I think there is something wrong after first successful write to the SD card. After the first loop iteration, it seems like all data is basically noise on the SPI bus.

I am using the [Adafruit ADA254 microSD breakout Board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/254), which has a card detect pin, so I first check to see if an SD card is inserted, and then write to the file.

**Question:** Is there another or better way to switch SPI_MODES on each loop? is there anything more I need to consider so I end up back to SPI_MODE1 appropriately for the MAX31856 thermocouples?

Below is the pertinent code for what I have going on...

```
void setup(){
   int sdCard = 36;
   char filename[10] = "test.txt";
}

void loop(){
....code to read thermocouples ...

///THEN THIS

  //lets confirm SD card is still in socket before writing
  CardDetect = digitalRead(37);
  if(CardDetect == HIGH){
    
     SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
     SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV4);
     SPI.setBitOrder(LSBFIRST);
     digitalWrite(sdCard, LOW);
     sd.begin(sdCard, SD_SCK_MHZ(1));
    //LETS START SAVING DATA
          myFile.open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL);
          myFile.write(now.unixtime());
          myFile.write(",");
            for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
              myFile.print(TEMP[i]);
              myFile.write(",");
            }
          myFile.println();
          myFile.close();
          digitalWrite(sdCard, HIGH);
          SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1);
          SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV16);
          SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
          delay(200);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: if your question is `how do I debug the code?`, then remove all sensor code and see if file is written without crashing

Comment: @jsotola - the file is writing no problem on first iteration. However, after the first loop of the code, the SPI bus 'glitches' and I does not read sensors correctly

Comment: This is more likely the SD card or level translator itself interfering with the SPI bus. I never share an SPI bus with an SD card - always have it on its own dedicated bus.

Comment: @Majenko I feared this... I needed all the digital pins, hence why the project is built around the arduino Mega - any way to add a second SPI bus (software maybe)?

Wait - are you the author of: https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/SoftSPI ?

Comment: I might be. Been so long I have no idea how well it works. I've become so used to working with chips with 6 SPI busses built in I've had no cause to use it for a number of years...

Comment: the Adafruit's library has built in software SPI. use the constructor with pin numbers `Instantiate MAX31856 object and use software SPI pins`

Comment: @Juraj I have done that, each MAX31856 thermocouple object is built by their software SPI pins, eg: ```Adafruit_MAX31856(22,50,51,52)```

Again - my code works fine until I get to the SD card logic. If I remove the SD card logic, code works too. It has something to do with the SPI bus after I read/write to SD card

Comment: In case you are using a 'cheap' SD reader, the SPI bus cannot be shared. I had more luck with a SD data logger card. It is related to thri-stating.

Comment: @Michel im using the Adafruit breakout board... not cheap. I believe it has something to do with different SPI_MODES between my spi devices

Comment: @NRav ok then it's probably not the issue I had long time ago.

Comment: don't use the hardware SPI pins for software SPI

Comment: @Juraj I was under the impression that declaring the pins was just redundant... or am I misinterpreting that? In which case, any 3 digital pins can be SPI bus pins?

Comment: those are the pins which software SPI will use. by using this constructor you activate software SPI on selected pins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who has a similar issue with the SPI Bus, `SdFat` library has a Software SPI option built in (example [here](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/master/examples/SoftwareSpi/SoftwareSpi.ino)).

You need to modify your `SdFat/SdFatConfig.h` file, but that is minimal. Once you have the microSD card module on a separate bus, it will not corrupt the main SPI Bus.

Switching the SD Card module to it's own bus rectified the issue. Keep in mind that Software SPI comes with a speed penalty.